# Ajuda com requisição AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tenho essa função que busca no banco de dados a quantidade dos produtos no estoque.

```
public function contarProduto() {
    try {
        $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();
        $sql = "select id_produto as produto, sum(quantidade) as quantidade from estoque where tipo = 'entrada' group by id_produto;";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $saida = array();
        $i = -1;
        while ($rs = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $i = $i + 1;
            $saida[$i] = array("id" => ($rs['produto']), "qtd" => utf8_encode($rs['quantidade']));
        }
        return $saida[0];
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

E essa página que transforma o conteúdo em JSON

```
<?php
require_once 'Modelo/DAO/EstoqueDAO.php';
$estoque = new EstoqueDAO();
$jason = $estoque->contarProduto();

echo json_encode($jason);
?>
```

Tenho esse código que faz uma requisição AJAX só que retorna todos os produtos, mesmo passando uma `data` que no caso é `id:1`

```
var t = {id: 1};
$.getJSON("http://localhost/impressoras/newEmptyPHPWebPage.php",t, function 
(d) {
console.log(d.qtd);
});
```

Preciso que essa requisição retorne apenas o produto que for mandado pelo `id`. alguém pode me ajudar?

No caso quando o cliente escolher um produto atravez de um select, automaticamente aparecera a quantidade no estoque, por isso nao posso passar o id pelo sql.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve acrescentar o parametro `id`, passado na requisição ajax, para a sua query. Uma abordagem seria alterar essa linha `$jason = $estoque->contarProduto();` para `$jason = $estoque->contarProduto($_GET['id']);`.

E por fim altere a sua função para:

```
//receba o parametro id
public function contarProduto($idProduto) {
    try {
        $pdo = Conexao::getInstance();
        //aplique o parametro id na consulta, como você está usando prepare statement, altere para o group by para :id_produto
        $sql = "select id_produto as produto, sum(quantidade) as quantidade from estoque where tipo = 'entrada' group by  :id_produto ;";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        //agora faça o bind com o variavel $idProduto
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_produto', $idProduto);
        $stmt->execute();
        $saida = array();
        $i = -1;
        while ($rs = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $i = $i + 1;
            $saida[$i] = array("id" => ($rs['produto']), "qtd" => utf8_encode($rs['quantidade']));
        }
        return $saida[0];
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela atenção.
Preciso de passar o id pela $.get pois tudo isso tem que acontecer sem atualizar  a pagina. Quando o cliente escolher um produto em um select automaticamente aparecerá a quantidade disponível no estoque, entao pegarei o id do produto que esta no selct e passarei atravez do $.get